# Laravel Illegal operator and value combination Exception on with() with belongsTo() relation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Call Model with a belongsTo() relation as following

```
class Call extends Model
{
    public function campaign()
    {
        $callStart = $this->call_start;
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Campaign','gsm_number','gsm_number')
        ->where(function($query) use($callStart){
            $query->where('end_date','=','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                ->orWhere('end_date','>=',$callStart);
        })->where(function($query) use($callStart){
            $query->where('start_date','=','0000-00-00 00:00:00')
                ->orWhere('start_date','<=',$callStart);
        });

    }
}
```

The logic of this relation is that, each call belongs to a campaign if gsm_numbers in both tables match and call_start from start_date in Campaign is either not set or less than call_start in Call model and end_date in Campaign model is wither not set or it is greater than call_start from Call Model

In Controller I do:

```
$calls = Call::orderBy('call_start','DESC')->get(); //in simplest form
return view('calls')->with('calls',$calls);
```

In View for campaigns listing I display campaign information as well using following

```
@foreach($calls as $call)
      {{ $call->campaign['name'] }}
@endforeach
```

No issue but I need to perform same issue with ajax calls as well so I need calls data along with campaigns. So I do the following

```
$calls = Call::with('campaign')->orderBy('call_start','DESC')
            ->get();

if($request->ajax()){
  return $calls
}
```

In this case I get exception `InvalidArgumentException in Builder.php line 464:
Illegal operator and value combination.`

Exception Stack:

```
in Builder.php line 464
at Builder->where('end_date', '>=', null, 'or')
at call_user_func_array(array(object(Builder), 'where'), array('end_date', '>=', null, 'or')) in Builder.php line 640
at Builder->where('end_date', '>=', null, 'or') in Builder.php line 656
at Builder->orWhere('end_date', '>=', null) in Call.php line 51
at Call->App\{closure}(object(Builder))
```

Answer (score 16):

You cannot perform a null comparison on a datetime field. You need to make sure $callStart is not null before adding a where clause `->orWhere('end_date','>=',$callStart);`

```
 $call->campaign['name']
```

works because $call exists. that is, it contains data. hence `$callStart = $this->call_start;` will not be null. but when you have

`$calls = Call::with('campaign')->orderBy('call_start','DESC')->get();`

the query builder calls your relation 'campaign', and evaluates your `$callStart = $this->call_start;` as  null, since Call is not yet a  valid model instance, no data is set to to it yet, hence call_start attribute will be null at that point.

Comment: $callStart can never be null because for all records in calls table, call_start column is not null. Problem is related when with() is used on conditional relation. Only when using with('campaigns'), $this->call_start inside belongsTo() is happening to be null. Why is this so?

Comment: "$callStart can never be null" - the errors you posted says otherwise

Comment: What I want to say is that records in table are completely valid with no null 'call_start' column. After further debugging only when using with, $this->call_start in belongsTo() relation happens to be null because "$this" is not being correctly referenced. $this->call_start is null because $this is empty. Why would $this be empty? Can you figure it out?

Comment: @DanishAltafSatti I updated my answer for more clarification.

Comment: Thanks a lot. now I understand completely. You have nailed it. Any other way to accomplish it?

Comment: I just added if else check for null variable in my closure, and its work! thanks man

Answer (score 0):

please check your

```
 dd($callStart)
```

hope is this not null

Also, check if the `$callStart` value has a date or not.