# Operators don't seem to work in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new to laravel, and I've been learning a few more things. But now I'm getting a error that I have never seen in plain PHP. Some operators that I test in the function catalog don't work, while others do. Only the =, != and <> work, while the <, >, >= and <= don't.

It gives me: "Illegal operator and value combination"; and also: `->where('Price', '(operator)', **null**)`. I have tried "wherenull" but doesn't work. Can anyone help me out on this one? I'm using laravel 5.4.

The code:

controller (in this case I have placed ">=" it doesn't work)

```
function catalog(Request $abc) {
    $categoryesc = $abc->categoryesc;
    $priceesc = $abc->priceesc;
    $categories = DB::table('categories')->pluck('Category', 'id');
    $robots = DB::table('robots')->where('Category_id', $categoryesc)->where('Price', '>=', $priceesc)->get();
    return view('catalog', compact('robots', 'categories'));
}
```

view

```
@extends('layouts.layout')
@include('header')

<main>
<div>Choose the category</div>
{!! Form::open(array('method' => 'GET')) !!}
    {!! Form::select('categoryesc', $categories) !!}
    {{ Form::number('priceesc') }}
    {!! Form::submit('Ok') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

<div>Choose the model</div>
<b>On this page ({{ $robots->count() }} robots)</b>

<div id="area1">
@foreach($robots as $robot)
  {!! Form::open(array('action' => 'RobotController@orders', 'method' =>  'GET')) !!}
  {!! Form::hidden('modelesc', $robot->Model) !!}
  {!! Form::submit($robot->Model) !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
</div>

</main>
```

the full error message is:

> InvalidArgumentException in Builder.php line 609: Illegal operator and value combination

***Apparent solution***

I think that I have solved this: I went to the file at `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\illuminate\database\query\builder.php` and at line 627 added "<=" (the operator that I want to use). Now it's working. Otherwise I'll return to this later.

Comment: can you provide the full text of the error?

Comment: Please check your data type? What type is Price?

Comment: @jacket414 - the full error message is: InvalidArgumentException in Builder.php line 609:
Illegal operator and value combination.

Comment: @Boris - Price´s data type is "int".

Comment: And what type is $priceesc? Can you hardcore it to int and test?

Comment: @Boris $priceesc is a "int" too. It comes from a number input. But what do you mean with "hardcore it to int and test?"

Comment: would u please `dd($abc->all())` and tell us if your `$abc->priceesc` is null or something else?

Comment: @AmrAly i have added that line to the function catalog and in the error it says that priceesc is null: "prepareValueAndOperator(null, '>', false) in Builder.php line 519" and also: "->where('Price', '>', null)"

Comment: there's a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35454512/3664960

Comment: no add it in the beginning like this `function catalog(Request $abc) { dd($abc->all())`.

Comment: @AmrAly i did that. It now shows a blank screen with only a "[ ]". What does that mean?

Comment: That means your `catalog(Request $abc)` haven't received any data from your from.

Comment: @davejal i have edited my question post with an apparent solution. Is it a good solution?

Answer (score 0):

At this point you should start troubleshooting the input for your `$robots` query.

Instead of returning the view return the values you get from all the queries before `$robots`. If any is incorrect start checking why (maybe it doesn't have any data or the wrong data)

```
function catalog(Request $abc) {
    $categoryesc = $abc->categoryesc;
    //$priceesc = $abc->priceesc;
    //$categories = DB::table('categories')->pluck('Category', 'id');
    //$robots = DB::table('robots')->where('Category_id', $categoryesc)->where('Price', '>=', $priceesc)->get();
    dd($categoryesc); // is this the correct value you want to send to the `$robots` query? If yes continue to next variable
}
```

Check the second variable:

```
function catalog(Request $abc) {
$categoryesc = $abc->categoryesc;
$priceesc = $abc->priceesc;
//$categories = DB::table('categories')->pluck('Category', 'id');
//$robots = DB::table('robots')->where('Category_id', $categoryesc)->where('Price', '>=', $priceesc)->get();
//return view('catalog', compact('robots', 'categories'));
dd($priceesc); // is this the correct value you want to send to the `$robots` query? If yes continue to next variable and so on
}
```

None of them should return an array. If one of the values is an array, your last query won't work.

Update:

Your form isn't sending the values to the `function catalog`

Comment: i checked both variables. All of them show a blank screen with only "null". How can i solve this?

Comment: As @Amraly already stated, your request is empty, something wrong with your form, hold on let me check the form

Comment: You're missing the url, something like this `{!! Form::open(['url' => url('the url')]) !!}`

Comment: i will update the initial post to include orders.php (to where the data is sent)

Comment: It's better to leave this post and ask a new question. Everything about this post is about the problem you described about the query. Not about the form not being correct

Comment: The answer to this question is that your data is not correct resulting in a wrong query being send (a query with empty values)

Comment: ok i will ask a new question. Its just that this error is strange because some operators work and others not.

Comment: The operators will work if you hard code the values with existing values, try that out for a second i.e. `$robots = DB::table('robots')->where('Category_id', 1)->where('Price', '>=', 1)->get();` If you have a category_id of 1 etc etc.

Comment: yes, if i harcode this way, it works. But of course this is not a solution. Hoe can i solve this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138280/discussion-between-davejal-and-adato).